# Oracle procedure compiling successfully but show errors

Tags: oracle, plsql, compiler-errors, ora-06550

Using `Oracle SQL Developer` I created a simple procedure. The procedure compiles successfully, but when I type the command:

```
execute CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT();

BEGIN CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT(); END;
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
execute CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT()
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Error starting at line : 2 in command -
BEGIN CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT(); END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Please help me to solve this. I know it's a small error. Also I have specified the data types, declarations of names correctly.

My procedure code is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT( 
  p_projectname IN VARCHAR2,
  p_description OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT DESCRIPTION
    INTO p_description
    FROM CMPPROJECT
   WHERE PROJECTNAME = p_projectname;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    p_description:= NULL;
    COMMIT;
END CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT;
```

Comment: The caller of the procedure expects the procedure to select something from a table, not that it also commits the entire transaction. The commit would be an unwanted side effect. 
Leave the commit to the main proces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
execute CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT();
BEGIN CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT();
 END;
```

1. **EXECUTE** is **SQL*Plus** command.
2. You are not passing the required **parameters** to the **procedure**. You have declared two parameters for your procedure:

```
p_projectname IN VARCHAR2,
p_description OUT VARCHAR2
```

So, you need to **declare** the required parameters and then pass it to the procedure:

```
DECLARE
  proj_desc VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT('project_name', proj_desc);
  -- use the OUT value of proj_desc later
END;
/
```

On a side note, you do not need **COMMIT** at all. It is required to permanently commit a **DML** and has nothing to do with a `SELECT ..INTO` clause.

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION INTO p_description FROM CMPPROJECT WHERE PROJECTNAME = p_projectname;
EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        p_description:= NULL;
COMMIT;  -- You don't need COMMIT at all
```

---

**UPDATE** A working demonstration:

**In PL/SQL:**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_emp(
  2      p_ename IN VARCHAR2,
  3      p_job OUT VARCHAR2)
  4  IS
  5  BEGIN
  6    SELECT job INTO p_job FROM emp WHERE ename = p_ename;
  7  END;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> sho err
No errors.
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    job VARCHAR2(20);
  3  BEGIN
  4    get_emp('SCOTT',JOB);
  5    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The output is '||job);
  6  END;
  7  /
The output is ANALYST

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**In SQL*Plus:**

```
SQL> VARIABLE JOB VARCHAR2(20);
SQL> EXECUTE get_emp('SCOTT', :JOB);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> PRINT JOB;

JOB
--------------------------------
ANALYST
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful commant lalit.somehow i am getting the errors, when i execute this procedure:::::ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

Comment: Did you try the way I suggested? Edit your question as show how are you doing.

Comment: DECLARE
  p_description VARCHAR2(2000);
BEGIN
  CMPPROJECTPROCSELECT('THIRD',p_description);
END;     I have using this to check the o/p.And aslo excluded commit from the stored procedure lalit..I am also trainee...pls bear me..Thanks in advance..

Comment: @KarthikPalchamy I have added a complete working demonstration as an example. See the update answer. just do the way I have demonstrated. Please mark it as answered, it would help others too!